# Can't set character_set_results to latin1

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I've decided to use Django 1.7 for the first time with Python 3.
I need to be able to work with legacy `latin1` database which contains `utf8` data. I know it sucks, but the database is so huge that it's really impossible to change this. So I tried following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql', // using MySQL-python fork with support for py3
    ...
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'init_command': "SET character_set_results = 'latin1'",
        #'read_default_file': '/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf', // I've also tried this one
    }
}
```

I've also tried python-mysql-connector from Oracle with following setup

```
DATABASES = {
    'ENGINE' : 'mysql.connector.django', // using MySQL-python fork with support for py3
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'option_files': ['/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf'],
    }
}
```

/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf

```
[client]
init-command='SET character_set_results = "latin1"'
# password, host, username
```

In both cases I can connect to database, but it seems like Django sets character_set_results back to utf8.

I've tried following

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as c:
   // I expect variable to be 'latin1'
   c.execute("show variables like 'character_set_results%'")
   c.fetchone() // returns ('character_set_results', 'utf8')

   // here I try to set it manually
   c.execute("SET character_set_results = 'latin1'")
   c.execute("show variables like 'character_set_results%'")
   c.fetchone() // returns ('character_set_results', 'latin1') // now it's OK
```

- I'm sure django uses `client.cfg` file and correct `[section]`, because it contains username/password and it successfully connects to the database
- When I use `mysql` command in the linux terminal which uses the same configuration file, everything works as expected

So I guess Django somehow enforces `character_set_results` variable to be `utf8`. Is it possible? Is there any way how can I solve this issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out (I don't know why I always find a solution a while after posting it to SO)

```
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created

def connection_setup(**kwargs):
    conn = kwargs['connection']
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SET character_set_results = 'latin1'")
        cursor.close()
```

I've tried it before with Oracle's `python-mysql-connector` and it threw

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

but it works with `MySQL-driver` py3 branch. I guess it can be a bug in `python-mysql-connector` or `Django` which I'll report. Maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: Please report a bug on bugs.mysql.com if the mysql connector python is throwing runtime error.

Comment: I also needed to call `conn.connection.set_character_set("latin1")` to ensure that the string_decoder in the mysql connection use the right charset for string-to-unicode conversion... (mysql-python=1.2.3, django=1.4, mysql=5.6)

Comment: How to set global all cursor must be latin-1 by default? Because my database all char field is latin1? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not really a full-blown answer but a bit too long for a comment so...

Django's MySQL wrapper sets `kwargs['charset']='utf8'` as default in `DatabaseWrapper.get_connection_params()`. This dict is then passed to MySQLdb's `Connection.__init__`, which documents that:

> charset
>       If supplied, the connection character set will be changed
>       to this character set (MySQL-4.1 and newer). This implies
>       use_unicode=True.

So a starting point might be to just add `"charset":"latin1"` in your `OPTIONS` dict ?

WARNING : I'm not sure it will solve your problem, and it might even create other problems but well, having utf8 encoded data in a latin1 database is certainly not the best starting point :-/ (been here, done that, and I can feel your pain).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've also tried setting `"charset":"latin1"` in `OPTIONS`, unfortunatelly with no luck

Comment: +1 for assuring me it's Django internal system that sets the parameter, helped me to find an answer, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

with mysql connector python in the client.cfg that you are using as an option file, in place of the init-command option(which is ignored by the connector) use write, charset=latin1, 
this will work.

```
[client]
charset=latin1
# password, host, username
```

Comment: This will not work, it has the same effect as `init-command`, the point is that Django always override this variable, I explained it in my answer