# How to set character_set_results latin1 mysql in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, character-encoding, latin1

I don't know how to connect to mysql db when db use latin1 encode.
What I am try and follow document and I am using `mysqlclient==1.3.5` here is my setting for database connection.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test_api',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': '192.168.59.103',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'latin1', 'use_unicode': False

        },
    }
}

37 Pháº©m Bá»“ tÃ¡t háº¡nh
Am mÃ¢y ngá»§
An cá»© kiáº¿t háº¡ 
An láº¡c tá»« tÃ¢m
An láº¡c tá»«ng bÆ°á»›c chÃ¢n
Ãnh SÃ¡ng Tá»« Bi
```

But it not success so next I try to use pymysql to write a simple script below and it work fine.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.59.103', port=3306, user='admin', passwd='123456', db='test_api', use_unicode=False)

customers = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
customers.execute('SET character_set_results=\'latin1\'')
customers.execute('SELECT *  FROM bz_media_album ORDER BY name_vn')
for customer in customers:
    print customer['name_vn']

37 Phẩm Bồ tát hạnh
Am mây ngủ
An cứ kiết hạ 
An lạc từ tâm
An lạc từng bước chân
Ánh Sáng Từ Bi
```

I also find https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685134/523075
But don't know how to implement it.

Because all my table use latin1 and my question is how to character_set_results for django cursor because I use django and tastypie to develop mobile api. I also has model and resource.

Answer (score 1):

Was the first line supposed to be `Phẩm Bồ tát hạnh`?  If so, the probably this is what happened:

- You had utf8-encoded bytes in the client
- You executed `SET NAMES latin1` (or the equivalent in python/django)
- The column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`

Everything needs to be ut8.  But to fix the data, you need the [2-step ALTER](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter), which effectively says to do

- `ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;`
- `ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;`

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (NOT NULL, etc) was already on the column.

Recommend you test this outside production.

**Edit**

You have garbage in the database.  Any attempt to shortcut the fixing of the table(s) will probably lead to a worse mess.

This *might* make the output "look" right:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(column_name) USING utf8)
```

Comment: But I don't want to touch in current db because it has a lot of services using this db already.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem using the following signal:

```
# apps.my_app.signals.py
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(connection_created)
def set_character_set_results(*args, connection, **kwargs):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = \'latin1\'')
```

This then needs wiring up [in the usual way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions).

This should work with Mysql 4.1 or higher.

Our use case was reading from a mysql database of which we also didn't want to alter the encoding as it was being read and written to from a legacy system.  We also had another (postgres) database, so the actual code was more like:

```
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(connection_created)
def set_character_set_results(*args, connection, **kwargs):
    if connection.alias == 'legacy':
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = \'latin1\'')
```

Comment: Note that the `MySQLdb.python` module has a [`set_character_set` method](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/d34fac681487541e4be07e6978e0db233faf8252/MySQLdb/connections.py#L301) which might turn out to solve problems beyond simply reading correctly some non-ascii characters.